# Spreadsheet formula that can locate data in a row that is "left" of the lookup value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out "how to" locate data in a row (column C) based on a value that is in the same row, but in column J.

I tried using the `Vlookup` Function, but the search data (column J) needs to be to the left of the desired data (column C), but that isn't the case in my situation.

**EXAMPLE FILE**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JO7mor4SCnOCW2JRT3dhxpqSS1BPEjCpSPj1BAuZ_Qg/edit?usp=sharing

[image]
I'm trying to write a formula in cell `C22` that will find the value of `C21` in the range of `A4:F13` and then return the value found in column C of that row.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(C21, {J4:J14,C4:C14}, 2, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! Can you please explain the `{J4:J14,C4:C14}, 2, 0` portion of your solution?

Comment: @Mr.B sure. `VLOOKUP` will try to find the content of `C21` in virtual table `{J4:J14,C4:C14}` and if a match is found it will return `2` column from that virtual table. `0` stands for unsorted eg. returns value as appears in standard chronological order

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful explanation!

Answer (score 1):

A simple index Match will do it:

```
=INDEX(C4:C13,MATCH(MAX(J4:J13),J4:J13,0))
```